# How to crop image from camera preview (surface view) and save it instead of actual image captured bt camera like instagram app?

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

[image: This is instagram app]I have an activity with surface view (match parent-match parent), half of which is hidden by button. Is it possible to save only visible part of captured picture? I've tried to make the surface view smaller, but preview is either rotated in this case or stretched. I'm using android.hardware.camera1 btw

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_camera"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="uz.pages.yangiuz10.activity.CameraActivity">

    <SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/surface_camera"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorBackgroundText">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button_shot"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/shot_btn"
                android:background="@null"
                android:onClick="onPictureCapture"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Need to save only that visible part of image]

Comment: you Use surfaceView width & height  [match_parent] in .XML..that's why it will capture images in full screen mode...even if you did hide the Below part of surfaceView.

Comment: it takes full size surfaceview preview at Run time...i had same Problem.i also hide my SurfaceView parts same as you..the difference is you hide with button.and i hide with layout

Comment: i did cropping my captured image.because i did not found any solution for that.

Comment: @SagarAghara how did you crop it? Can you show your solution, please?

Comment: Crop means i Used my Own method...wait i will post..once you will try.ok....
you should use image width instead of height...in both parameters for Bitmap.

Comment: Check Here...this is same as you want...........http://42works.net/tutorials/easy-steps-to-set-square-mode-camera-in-android-like-instagram/

Comment: also Check this........https://kylewbanks.com/blog/tutorial-square-camera-with-preview-on-android

Comment: @SagarAghara thank you, the last one did work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below **Link** is Same as your Requirement's.

Please Check :

https://kylewbanks.com/blog/tutorial-square-camera-with-preview-on-android

Hope this will solve your problem...(: